# Mobile Hotspot, Smartphone or Router?

Tags: linux, privacy, android, usb, hotspot

I am using a laptop with dual boot Windows and Ubuntu. In addition, I am having another Linux distro installed on a usb thumb drive and using it only for certain things.

Generally speaking - if android devices are vulnerable in terms of privacy and security, does that mean that my linux will be vulnerable too if I use the Hotspot from android devices?

Are Mifi devices, all these jetpacks, any better than a smartphone for security and privacy?

Getting a mifi, a good plan simcard and using a Linux distro on a USB should be better than, using my linux installed on the laptop alongside with windows, and using my android phone as a hotspot?

I have access to unlimited data from a broadband provider, but don't have access to their hub3 device and can't configure any settings and I think its very unsecured as it is now. So that's why I am using mobile data for my laptop, thinking its more secure.

Would getting a mifi, mobile simcard and using a Linux distro on a USB thumb drive be a good idea?

**EDIT:**

HTC One M7 (Sense Version) with Android version 5.0.2
Unlimited mobile data from GiffGaff, O2 Network
Never used google services in my life, have disabled all google apps.

Opera Version 54.3.2672.50220, blocked cookies and allowed only certain sites storing and accessing cookies.

Linux 18.4 LTS 4.15.0-96-generic
UFW status verbose: 
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

Using three different browsers for different activities:

Opera - Version:67.0.3575.137 (All site settings are blocked, except few sites with allowed JavaScript and cookies clearing at exit)

Brave - Version 1.5.123 Chromium: 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit) (all sites restricted)

Firefox - 75.0 (64-bit) with tracking protection set on Strict

ProtonVPN installed on phone and laptop with secure connection services - still trying to understand should I use vpn on the phone or on the laptop, while using the mobile data on the laptop.

Comment: [Yikes!](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=1224&product_id=19997&version_id=188441&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=3&trc=183&sha=c9e7816dda7795e69fb3379ef317e3b8c3cca169) My immediate response would be to avoid anything with ancient versions of Android.

Comment: yeah I thought so too. Will buy some new android device. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are just too many unknowns to provide a clear answer to this question. The answer also depends a lot on your threat model - who exactly are you trying to protect yourself against? Family members and roommates? Strangers at Starbucks? Your Internet provider? Google? Government agencies? The important considerations will change heavily depending on what you consider to be your primary threat.

> Generally speaking - If android devices are vulnerable in terms of
>   privacy and security

It sounds like this is just an assumption you're making but I think it also requires more elaboration. Is there a specific Android device you are referring to? An old and unpatched Android device from an unreputable manufacturer will likely have as many security holes as swiss cheese, indeed. But a fully up-to-date device that is actively supported by a reputable company (e.g. Google's Pixel line) is arguably more secure than the majority of other devices you'd use on a regular basis - including Windows and Linux computers. Android devices do have significant privacy drawbacks in terms of the amount of data they share with Google, but it is unclear whether Google is part of your threat model or not.

> Does Mifi devices, all these jetpacks any better than a smartphone for
>   security and privacy?

Keep in mind that Mifi devices run software too - [very likely](https://timonpeng.com/reverse-engineering-gl-inet-mifi-router/) based on some form of Linux. That software may be old, unpatched, or poorly written just like any other software. So whether a Mifi device would be more secure again comes back to the specific device you are using and your threat model.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my post. I am trying to set up an environment to be secure and private as much as possible for crypto and stock trading. Will install a new Linux on a usb and will try to configure it to be as safe as much as possible. When I find out the best way to use internet, then will proceed.